# getting null decoded bitmap image in android base64

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I'm decoding encoded image string using base64 but it always return null.

I have encoded string using below code & stored it in class file -

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),R.drawable.img);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

ba1 is stored in java file & accessing it in my activity for decoding like -

```
MyStrings mMyString=new MyStrings();
String imageString=mMyString.image1;
Bitmap bm=decodeBase64(imageString);
```

But I'm getting bm as null always.Is there any solution to get image bitmap?

Comment: you have make little mistake.. that i have solve in below answer ... please try it  out.. hope it ll help you :)

Comment: @Vaishali its not working

Answer (score 0):

USE this way

```
 Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),R.drawable.img);
 ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
 byte[] byteArray = bao.toByteArray();
 String ba1= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: got exception  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64 while decoding string at byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(input, Base64.NO_WRAP);